# Multi-module maven jacoco setup for integration tests

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube, integration-testing, jacoco

I have maven setup with multiple modules, the setup looks something like this

```
root module
  - domain module 
  - repository module 
  - service module 
  - controllers module
```

Jacoco is correctly generating test coverage from unit tests and sonar is showing the correct percentage (let's say 20%). Surefire is used for unit tests.

For integration tests its more tricky, we use failsafe and integration tests generate `jacoco-it.exec` file which is scanned by sonar. My problem is that integration tests are located in the `controllers module` and it only shows test coverage of integration tests on classes that are inside controllers and not on classes that are in another module like service module. Because of this overall test coverage with integration tests increases to something like 21% instead of 35+%.

Is it possible to configure sonar and jacoco to measure test coverage with the integration tests of **all classes** instead of classes from same module only, if integration tests are in `controllers module`?

For reference, this is the relevant setup

```
<sonar.java.coveragePlugin>jacoco</sonar.java.coveragePlugin>
<sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
...
<plugin>
<groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
<artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.7.9</version>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
        <goals>
            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco.exec</destFile>
            <propertyName>surefireArgLine</propertyName>
        </configuration>
    </execution>

    <execution>
        <id>pre-integration-test</id>
        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <destFile>${project.build.directory}/jacoco-it.exec</destFile>
            <propertyName>failsafeArgLine</propertyName>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

I run my tests with `mvn verify` and scanner with `mvn sonar:sonar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can aggregate your coverage reports by writing them all to the same destination file.

For example, we're only covering unit tests in our multi-module projects at the moment, so our parent pom contains:

```
<properties>
    ...
    <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
    ...
</properties>
```

and

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
            <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
                <append>true</append>
            </configuration>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

This results in a single aggregated report for all modules.

I expect that a similar pattern could be applied to your jacoco IT configuration.

Comment: Its not really the same problem. In your case, you have unit tests inside modules and each unit tests correspond to classes from that same module. So everything is fine and sonar is doing the actual aggregation as you mentioned. In my case I have integration tests in module4 that also tests classes from module1,2 and 3 and jacoco-it.exec contains only execution details about classes from module4. So sonar will not be able to merge them.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking our unit tests are in many cases really integration tests because they in fact call code from other modules and we do collect the resulting code coverage.

Comment: I've just tried it and it works. This part is very smart `<append>true</append>` and writing in root module. Thank you @Steve C

Comment: How can I setup my parent pom and child poms to merge my integration tests in one file ? in my child pom I added `<sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>${project.basedir}/../target/coverage-merged.exec</sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths>` but what should I add in my parent pom ?